# Easy way shortened text in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, text-processing, text-extraction

I'm looking for customizable shortcut text in Android Java. I tried this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strxd = "Hello World XD";
    int xdindex = strxd.indexOf("XD");
    EditText et = new EditText(IssueActivity.this);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(strxd);
    ss.setSpan(
        new ImageSpan(
            IssueActivity.this,
            R.drawable.xd_emoji,
            DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE
            ),
        xdindex,
        xdindex + 2,
        0
        );
    et.setText(ss);
    setContentView(et);
    }
```

or like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(IssueActivity.this);
    rl.setLayoutParams(
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        );
    EditText publicEditor = new EditText(IssueActivity.this);
    publicEditor.setLayoutParams(
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        );
    publicEditor.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    EditText hintEditor = new EditText(IssueActivity.this);
    hintEditor.setLayoutParams(
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        );
    hintEditor.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    hintEditor.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    String publicText = "Hello World";
    ArrayList<Integer> spaceIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int nextIndex = 0;
    int tmpIndex = 0;
    while (nextIndex != -1) {
        tmpIndex =  publicText.substring(nextIndex).indexOf(" ");
        if (tmpIndex == -1) {
            nextIndex = -1;
            }
        else {
            nextIndex += tmpIndex;
            spaceIndexes.add(nextIndex);
            nextIndex++;
            }
        }
    String hintText = "";
    int loop = spaceIndexes.size();
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        k = i == 0 ? spaceIndexes.get(i) : (spaceIndexes.get(i) - spaceIndexes.get(i - 1) - 1);
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            hintText += " ";
            }
        hintText += "•";
        }
    publicEditor.setText(publicText);
    hintEditor.setText(hintText);
    rl.addView(hintEditor);
    rl.addView(publicEditor);
    setContentView(rl);
    }
```

There is a problem here. Everything is working successful but can this reference of shortened text be to typeface graphics, layout widgets or like `ReplacementSpan` objects as shortcut and acceptable?

Or in alternative code, spanned text printed on two `EditText`. The method will be bottleneck for long texts. If I call `Editable` object of `publicEditor` with `getText()`, code not returned masked text object. Is this job possible with one `EditText`.

Shortened text issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.